# Linux - remap Ctrl-[ key

Tags: linux, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

On Linux, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> key combination appears to be equivalent to hitting the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. I would like to define the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> as a shortcut in Emacs but I am unable to because by the time the keystroke gets to Emacs it looks like the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key was pressed. Is there anyway to disable this behavior so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> simply means <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>?

Running Ubuntu 9.10 with GNOME.

Comment: Which linux? Which window manager?

Comment: which xterm are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're running Emacs directly under a windowing system (Cocoa, MS-DOS, Windows, X, ...) and not inside a text terminal (gnome-terminal, konsole, rxvt, xterm, ...), it's possible.

```
(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-\[] [(control left_bracket)])
(define-key key-translation-map [escape] [?\e])
(define-key function-key-map [escape] nil)
(define-key function-key-map [?\e] nil)
(when (boundp 'local-function-key-map)
  ;;(define-key local-function-key-map [escape] nil)
  (defun remove-escape-from-local-function-key-map ()
    (define-key local-function-key-map [?\e] nil)
    (define-key local-function-key-map [escape] nil))
  (add-hook 'term-setup-hook 'remove-escape-from-local-function-key-map))
```

---

There are three different input events at play here:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, i.e., the `control` modifier together with a key that sends the character `[`. Emacs would normally show this as **`C-[`** (and `C-[` accepted by `kbd`), if it didn't have a special case for this, as explained below.
- Character number 27, which is sent by the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on some systems. Emacs shows this as **`ESC`** when displaying key sequences, and **`\e`** in strings.
- The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key itself (in X Window, this means the `Escape` keysym). Emacs shows this as **`escape`** unless translated (see below).

Emacs normally translates `escape` into `ESC`, but this is done at a relatively high level, in **`function-key-map`**, so it can be overridden by modifying `function-key-map` or by defining a binding for `escape` in the global keymap or a local keymap. GNU Emacs 23 introduces `local-function-key-map` which applies per terminal type.

Emacs always translates `C-[` into `ESC`, at a very low level (in `keyboard.c`). This is not configurable.

However Emacs provides a way to translate keys at a relatively low level: **`key-translation-map`**. This applies before any global or local binding, but only for keys that are not in `function-key-map`. So the trick is to exchange `ESC` and `escape` at that point.

These mechanisms are described in the Emacs Lisp manual under the heading "Translation keymaps".

---

By the way, similar principles apply to

- `C-i`, `TAB`, `\t` `tab`
- `C-m`, `RET`, `\r`, `return`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your xterm, you might be able to use `bindkey`.  Try executing this command at the shell prompt:

```
bindkey ^] tty-dsusp
```